# Configuring WCF Service on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, deployment

This is my first time using WCF. It was very easy to develop the application however it's turning me nuts to deploy on IIS.

I've tried everything to deploy it, however the client started throwing unauthorized user exception (or something like that) to an Undefined exception (after countless changes in web.config file and app.config file).

I'm back to the default configurations which work fine in VS (cassini).

Any quick pointers or some link to a detailed tutorial would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MBTService.Service1Behavior"
        name="MBTService.MBTService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MBTSTBO.IMBTService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MBTService.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx

Comment: @Davide Piras - I've seen that tutorial but it didn't really help me much.

Comment: if deploying on IIS (Windows Server 2008), you must install WCF first ... Control Panel > Server Manager > Add Feature > .NET {version} > WCF ... turn on both the HTTP and NON-HTTP options for WCF ... there are also 7+ differences depending on complexity for HTTP vs. HTTPS setup in your web.config

Comment: .. if you have real specific questions for this one, feel free to email me at wcfguy at yahoo dot com .. although I won't check my email until evenings

Comment: @MacGyver I'm deploying on Windows 7 and Yes I have WCF Installed. Infact I can access it through add service reference in VS but then when running the application an Exception is thrown :/

Comment: Can you add the exception here?  If you want to email me your code, I can take a look for you later

Comment: Can you post the exact error that your service throws when you host in IIS? Also make sure of the App pool under which your service runs. Make sure its targetted toward the correct .NET framework

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to your case, however WCF Tracing is generally a really good tool to diagnose WCF configuration problems. You can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) how you can configure WCF tracing, it is really simple, the WCF runtime will basically emit some information into a .svclog file

Then you can analyze the log with the [Service Trace Viewer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) (it is in All Programs->Visual Studio 2010->Microsoft Windows SDK Tools), and see what went wrong during specific requests, it gives much more information than the exception messages.

Answer (score 0):

Jonny,

This is a long shot but once I had the same problem (unauthorized access) and the problem was that some files (downloaded from a webmail) was blocked by windows. As soon I unblocked these files the web service started to work fine.

Hope it helps.